# Can't get simple c# craps game to work correctly

Tags: c#

In craps, two 6 sided dice are rolled. If the result is a 7 or 11. The player or  wins automatically. If a 2, 3, or 12 is rolled, the player loses automatically. However, if another number is rolled, that number becomes the "point". The player rolls again until either they roll the point again or a 7. If the point is rerolled the player wins. If a 7 is rolled, this time it is a loss.

I'm having two issues with my code

1. My score counter adds one to the score when the player needs to roll again, and doesn't win
2. The point and total are always equal and so it just continues to ask to roll again.

State is used to say whether this is the first roll or one of subsequent rolls. I have omitted some of the code which is only used to display images of dice.

```
int die1;
int die2;
int total;
int state = 1;           
int point =0;
int point2;
int score = 0;

Random rand = new Random();
die1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
die2 = rand.Next(1, 7);
total = (die1 + die2);

txtDie1.Text = die1.ToString();
txtDie2.Text = die2.ToString();
txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();

if (state == 1)
{
    if (total == 7 || total == 11)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "You are a winner!";
        score++;
        txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        state = 1;

    }
    if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "You lose. Play again!";
        score --;
        txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        state = 1;

    }
    if (total == 4 || total == 5 || total == 6 || total == 8 || total == 9 || total == 10)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "Roll again!";
        point = int.Parse(txtTotal.Text);
        txtPoint.Text = point.ToString();
        state = 2;
    }
}
if (state == 2)             
{
    if (total == point)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "You are a winner!";
        score ++;
        txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        state = 1;
    }
    if (total == 7)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "You lose. Play again!";
        score --;
        txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        state = 1;
    }
    if (total != 7 || total != point)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = "Roll again!";
        state = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, change your code to read

```
else if (state == 2)
```

As written, your code first goes through the `if (state==1)` section and then immediately proceeds into the `if (state==2)` section.

Also, you have left out the the looping and flow control portion of your code. You might be redefining state=1 on every pass -- make sure that's outside the loop when `state==2`.